# Installing/linking g95 on osx

Tags: macos, fortran, ln

I found these libraries: http://www.g95.org/downloads.shtml. I downloaded the `x86 OSX` binaries, unzipped the file, and did `ln -s bin/i686-apple-darwin10.3.0-g95 /usr/local/bin/g95`, and added chmod +rx permissions to all these files, but I still can't run the g95 executable.

```
g95-install$ ls -la *
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 kilojoules  staff  138126 Jan 17  2013 G95Manual.pdf
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 kilojoules  staff     523 Jul 15 22:43 INSTALL

bin:
total 352
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 kilojoules  staff     102 Jan 17  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 kilojoules  staff     204 Jul 15 22:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 kilojoules  staff  176968 Jan 17  2013 i686-apple-darwin10.3.0-g95

lib:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 kilojoules  staff  102 Jul 15 22:39 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 kilojoules  staff  204 Jul 15 22:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 kilojoules  staff  102 Jul 15 22:39 gcc-lib

$ ln -s bin/i686-apple-darwin10.3.0-g95 /usr/local/bin/g95

$PATH
-bash: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/kilojoules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin: No such file or directory
$ g95
-bash: g95: command not found
```

Why isn't there a brew formula for this?

Comment: You could try g95. Intel Fortran definitely works but you cannot brew it, obviously. But without code, I have to assume that programmer error, and not the compiler, is responsible.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the tip. Can you check out my edited question? I'm having trouble installing the g95 compiler.

Comment: I honestly don't know because I have no issue using GCC and Intel Fortran on my Mac. Why not post your code and try to solve the real problem.

Comment: @Jeff my code seems too complex to post... Setting up Sandia Lab's DAKOTA is involved in itself, and I have mpi communication enabled on top of that. The code also involves the setup of several additional packages. I have posted my error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445696/how-to-debug-fortran-internal-error-list-formatted-write-bad-type in hopes of help debugging my problem. I was able to link my `mpif90` compiler to the f95 compiler, and ran into the same issue. As you diagnosed, this was not a compiler issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is what you need to post.

Comment: Isn't it better to use an absolute path like "ln -s <g95-install-dir>/bin/i686-apple-darwin10.3.0-g95 /usr/local/bin/g95" or something like that? I have tried g95 on my Mac mini (OSX10.6) and it seems to be working.